# how to disallow Specefic url Being index

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-media

i have about 200 URLs distributed in /3/2024 Folder with ".torrent" suffix (wordpress knowen as ducument)

Like : https://website/wp-content/uploads/*2024*/*03*/*diffrent_names*.torrent

Recently i got crawled and not index from Google S-console.
How Can i prevent index just this Type of files ? changes in robot.txt or Specific php code maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add rules to your robots.txt file to disallow search engines from crawling the .torrent files. However, keep in mind that this method relies on the cooperation of search engine bots and is not entirely foolproof. Add the following lines to your robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/2024/03/*.torrent
```

This rule tells all compliant search engine bots not to crawl any URLs that match the pattern ending with .torrent in the specified folder.

Comment: the problem is The storage location of files changes with time and generates new Queries. not good solution, i had to add every Month in robot.txt can i use Star * for changed Variables ?

Comment: Given that the .torrent files are moved to new folders each month, you can adjust the robots.txt directive to encompass any directory within your uploads folder. 

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/*.torrent
```
This rule is designed to match any .torrent file within the wp-content/uploads directory, regardless of the subdirectory it resides in. By omitting the specific year and month path, the wildcard * will apply the rule to .torrent files across all folders under uploads.

Please upvote if this solves your issue.